# native_takePicture() error when pressing button to take picture

Tags: java, android, sdk, camera, android-camera

I've been trying to look for a similar error but I'm having a hard time... I'm still new to android development, but hopefully someone can shine some direction.

I have a camera app that can preview, but when I tried to click on a button to take the picture, my app crashes. Can someone help me?

[PhotoActivity.java]

```
public class PhotoActivity extends Activity {
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

    protected static final String TAG = "Activity";
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photo);

        mCamera = getCameraInstant();
        mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);

        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mCameraPreview);

        // Add a listener to the Capture button
        Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // get an image from the camera
                    Log.e("log", "mPicture"+mPicture);

                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                }
            }
        );  
    }

    PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback(){
     @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if(pictureFile==null){

                return;
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());

            } catch (IOException e){
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());

            }
        }

    };



    /**
     * Helper method to access the camera returns null if
     * it cannot get the camera or does not exist
     * @return
     */
    private Camera getCameraInstant(){
        Camera camera = null;

        try{
            camera=Camera.open();
        }catch (Exception e){
            // cannot get camera or does not exist
        }
        return camera;
    }

    /** Create a File for saving the image */
    private File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");

        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");

        return mediaFile;
    }

}
```

Sorry for all the coding, but I'm really in need of some help... Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED**

[CameraPreview.java]

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = "Preview";
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    //Constructor that obtains context and camera
    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        //this.mCamera = camera;
        this.mCamera = camera;
        this.mSurfaceHolder = this.getHolder();
        this.mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this); // we get notified when underlying surface is created and destroyed
        this.mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); //this is a deprecated method, is not requierd after 3.0
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = Camera.open();

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);

            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // left blank for now
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Stopping preview in SurfaceDestroyed().");
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format,
            int width, int height) {


        if(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface()==null){
            //preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }catch(Exception e){
            //ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // intentionally left blank for a test
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

**Error**

```
05-09 21:19:29.013: E/AndroidRuntime(3823): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 21:19:29.013: E/AndroidRuntime(3823): java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
05-09 20:21:01.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
    05-09 20:21:01.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:746)
    05-09 20:21:01.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:710)
    05-09 20:21:01.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at com.liu.photo.PhotoActivity$2.onClick(PhotoActivity.java:73)
    05-09 20:21:01.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2486)
    05-09 20:21:01.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9130)
    05-09 20:21:01.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    05-09 20:21:01.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    05-09 20:21:01.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    05-09 20:21:01.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3703)
    05-09 20:21:01.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-09 20:21:01.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    05-09 20:21:01.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
    05-09 20:21:01.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
    05-09 20:21:01.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is this what the stack trace is? I'm very new, still learning the terms as well. Thank you

Comment: Will you post the stack trace?

Comment: Also, post source of `CameraPreview` please

Comment: @JasonRobinson Hello, I think thats the stack trace? (LogCat)? I'm still new to the term, and also I've updated to show CameraPreview. I appreciate the help

Comment: can you post a full stack trace? This one is cut on top, so there is no error explanation.

Comment: Yes it is, almost. The actual exception being thrown is a line or two above where you started. Include that as well please.

Comment: @alex.veprik Hello, I think I got it now?

Comment: it says that you call takePicture after releasing the camera. So, ou need to add logs to all the places in your code where you invoke camera.release() and check in logcat which place is causing a camera release before you take a shot. This is how I would go about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these two lines from the `surfaceCreated` method:

```
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = Camera.open();
```

You've already opened the `Camera` object in your `Activity`, no need to release it and reopen it again.

**Edit** You should actually remove your whole implementation of `surfaceCreated` and just leave the implementation empty. You're just repeating what you've already done in `surfaceChanged`, which is the important place to implement it anyway.

Comment: If I remove everything from SurfaceCreated, I don't get the preview anymore?

Comment: in your `surfaceChanged` method you're calling `startPreview()`, so I don't see why not. I see you're catching any exceptions there. Do you see anything in your LogCat getting print out around those lines?

Comment: Now, I'm getting more errors. After I put everything back to the original, i get a 
`05-09 22:18:17.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6014): java.lang.NullPointerException

05-09 22:18:17.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6014):  at com.liu.photo.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:33)
` error now

Comment: then I removed everything again, it goes back to where preview disappears. In the logcat, it says that `Error starting camera preview: null`

Comment: It says that because you're printing that out when you catch the exception. add `e.printStackTrace()` to that `catch` block so we can see the real error

Comment: I figured out why I didn't have the preview, `mCamera.setPreviewDisplay()` was passing `mSurfaceHolder`, while it should be passing just `surfaceHolder`

Comment: However, it gets pretty buggy though, sometimes it would not work, and it would work... I added `e.printStackTrace()` but nothing comes out.

Comment: Once everything is set up and `onSurfaceChanged` has executed, the only methods you need past this point is `takePicture` and `startPreview` (which you call in the JPEG callback), so make sure you're not making unnecessary calls.

Answer (score -1):

Please see this page:
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html
And make sure you follow the rules.
Especially pay attention that you must start preview before you take a picture.